# The requested URL was not found on this server' in XAMPP; Used Answers in Other Threads

Tags: codeigniter, http-status-code-404, codeigniter-3

I am using the latest version of CodeIgniter and XAMPP.  **I have searched stackoverflow and followed te suggestion from other threads with the same problem, to no avail.**

I have several CI projects running oin my localhost b(each with their own CI install).  I recently started a new project and went through the following steps to remove index.php from appearing in the URL:

1. Changed `$config['index_page'] = "index.php"` to
   `$config['index_page'] = ''` in config.php
2. Changed  `$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO"` to
   `$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"` in config.php.
3. Updated the .htaccess file to the following:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
   </IfModule>
   ```
4. Restarted apache

Yet I am still getting this error.

I have confirmed that mod_rewrite is installed in my XAMPP config.  Plus, I am using rewrite rules for the other projects on my locolhost and they are working fine.  I also made sure that update the base_url in the config:  `$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/folder_name';`

I have tried variations on the .htaccess file that I have found in other answers, yet an still at a loss.  I've done this before; what's different!?

EDIT: I am only getting this error when trying to explicitly go to a controller/method.  I have the default controller set to my login controller, so going to http://localhost/folder_name correctly hits the Login/login() controller/method.  However, if I change the url to go to http://localhost/folder_name/login/login, I get the 404 error.  However, http://localhost/folder_name/index.php/login/login/ eorks just fine still.

Comment: Is your application inside folder_name or is your login controller something like application/controllers/folder_name/login?

Comment: My application is inside of folder_name.

Comment: And .htaccess is under folder_name?

Comment: Correct, on same level as application folder.

Comment: Just to confirm that your .htaccess file is what it says it is... What happens if you type something in that's just junk to cause a 500 Server Error? Do you get an error? If you don't check the files name... make sure it don't have a hidden .txt or some other nonsense...

Answer (score 1):

I my self use XAMPP. and windows 10

Inside your project folder place the htaccess

- htdocs > folder_name
- htdocs > folder_name > .htaccess

---

Here is one I use

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then on the config.php

```
| URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
| WITH a trailing slash:
|
|   http://example.com/

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/folder_name/';

$config['index_page'] = '';
```

> Some case you will need to make sure you have the class and filename set where only the first letter is upper case. Explained here [naming classes](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#class-and-method-naming) and here [filenames](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming)

Comment: Yes, this is where I have the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

Add `RewriteBase` with your `project folder name`. 
Change your `.htaccess` to

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project_folder_name
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```